# How to set default queue in ActiveMq

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using apache-activemq-5.9.0. I have a created a queue (MYQUEUE) manually, with the help of admin user. I have a iot device which sending data to IP:XXXXXX PORT:61616.

IOT device doesn't know about MYQUEUE. How i should configure activemq.So that i can collect all the data(from 61616 port) to MYQUEUE. I can't change the program of iot device.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ does not have such a thing as default queue. Your device will send to a queue (whatever the name is), as there is no way you can send data to ActiveMQ without specifying queue or topic.

What you can do, once you figure out the actual queue name the device has, is to setup a composite queue that forwards messages to your special queue.

Simply enter the this block in your activemq.xml configuration file.

```
 <destinationInterceptors>
  <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    <virtualDestinations>
      <compositeQueue name="DEVICE.QUEUE.1234">
        <forwardTo>
          <queue physicalName="MYQUEUE" />
        </forwardTo>
      </compositeQueue>
    </virtualDestinations>
  </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```